# Managing multiple builds in Sublime Text

Tags: process, build, sublimetext

I've searched a fair bit for the answer to this but haven't found the answer. I want to use sublime text to run projects but I keep getting hung up on the same issue.

If I run my project, say a server, in Sublime Text and rerun it - forgetting to kill the initial process - Sublime's terminal loses reference to the old process and I have to go manually kill the process.

Is there a way to manage multiple builds within Sublime? An actual use case (with isn't me being silly and forgetting to kill the existing process) would be to have a server running and then run unit tests against it.

Has anyone figured out a neat way of managing this? At the very least I'd like some way of configuring Sublime to kill the last build before starting the new one - if managing multiple isn't possible.

Thanks